# How ReadLine works in .NET

Tags: c#, memory, memory-management

Let's say I have a 1 GB text file and I want to read it. If I try to open this file, I would get an "Memory Overflow" error. I know, the usual answer is "Use StreamReader.ReadLine() method". But I am wondering how this works. If the program which uses ReadLine method wants to get a line, it will have to open the entire text file sooner or later. As far as I know, files are stored on the disk and they can be opened in memory in an "all or nothing" principle. If only one line of my 1 GB text file is stored in a memory at a time by using a ReadLine() method, this means that we have to disk I-O for every line of my 1 GB text file while reading it. Isn't this a terrible thing to do for performance?

I'm so confused and I want some details about this.

Comment: FYI, `ReadLine` is not part of C# - it's part of .NET.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> this means that we have to disk I-O for every line of my 1 GB text file

No, there are lots of layers between your ReadLine() call and the physical disk, designed to not make this a problem. The ones that matter most:

- FileStream, the underlying class that does the job for StreamReader, uses a buffer to reduce the number of ReadFile() calls.  Default size is 4096 bytes
- ReadFile() reads file data from the file system cache, not the disk.  That *may* result in a call to the disk driver, but that's not so common.  The operating system is smart enough to guess that you are likely to read *more* data from the file and pre-reads it from the disk as long as that is cheap to do and RAM isn't being used for anything else.  It typically slurps an entire disk cylinder worth of data.
- The disk drive itself has a cache as well, usually several megabytes.

The file system cache is by far the most important one.  Also a tricky one because it stops your from accurately profiling your program.  When you run your test over and over again, your program in fact *never* reads from the disk, only the cache.  Which makes it unrealistically fast.  Albeit that a 1 GB file might not quite fit, depends how much RAM you have in the machine.

Answer (score 1):

Usually behind the scenes a `FileStream` object is opened which reads a large block of your file from disk and pulls it into memory. This block acts as a `cache` for ReadLine() to read from, so you don't have to worry about each ReadLine() causing a disk access.

Answer (score 0):

Terrible thing for the performance of what?

Obviously it should be faster, given you have the memory available to deal the whole file in memory.

Finding and allocating a contiguous block is a cost though.

A gig is a significant block of ram, if your process has it, what's hurting?

Swapping could easily hurt more than streaming.

Do you need all the file at once, Do you need it all the time?

If you went to read / write. What would that do to you?

What if the file went to 2 gig?

You can optimise for one factor. Before you do, you've got to make sure it's the right one, and above all you have to remember this is a real machine. You have a finite amount of resources, so optimisation is always robbing Peter to pay Paul. Peter might get upset...